# Where to put universal-router in React and how to define a link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

These are pretty basic questions, but the docs of `universal-router` don't explain this, and the examples it gives don't seem to work in my React project.

I have this in my `index.js`:

```
import Router from 'universal-router';
import { HomeComponent, HelpComponent, AboutComponent } from './home.jsx';

const routes = [
    { path: '/', action: () => <HomeComponent /> },
    { path: '/home', action: () => <HomeComponent /> },
    { path: '/about', action: () => <AboutComponent /> },
    { path: '/help', action: () => <HelpComponent /> },
    { path: '*', action: () => <h1>Nope.</h1> }
];

const router = new Router(routes);

router.resolve({ path: '/' }).then(component => {
    ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById('router-outlet'));
});

router.resolve({ path: '/help' }).then(component => {
    ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById('router-outlet'));
});

router.resolve({ path: '/about' }).then(component => {
    ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById('router-outlet'));
});
```

And this in my `App` component, a very simple menu:

```
export class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
                <div>
                    <a href="/">Root</a> |&nbsp;
                    <a href="/home">Home</a> |&nbsp; 
                    <a href="/help">Help</a> |&nbsp;
                    <a href="/about">About</a> |&nbsp;
                    <a href="/uijsklfdsse">404</a>
                </div>
                );
    }
}
```

As you see, this is pretty straightforward, I am just trying to figure how to get this working. It is almost exactly what's written [here,](https://github.com/kriasoft/universal-router/blob/master/docs/api.md) yet it doesn't work. For some reason it's always the `AboutComponent` which gets called, and it seems like the browser is refreshing the entire page when I click a link, so it's not behaving as a SPA. I have a feeling that I am putting the route definitions to the wrong place, but where am I supposed to put it? And is this how I am supposed to define links?

I am using `universal-router` because `React-router` says upon installation that it's deprecated and replaced by this thing. Let me know if it was a bad idea.

Answer (score 7):

Your routes look fine. You can prevent the browser from refreshing by handling the default href behavior. ie `onClick(event) { event.preventDefault(); }`

For using the window [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) and managing push state, you can use this [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) plugin, which I'd recommend, or you could go about it manually or with some other plugin.

To make your router more flexible, you can resolve your routes dynamically with a function, that way you can call it whenever you want.

Instead of

```
router.resolve({ path: '/' }).then(component => {
    ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById('router-outlet'));
});

router.resolve({ path: '/help' }).then(component => {
    ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById('router-outlet'));
});

router.resolve({ path: '/about' }).then(component => {
    ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById('router-outlet'));
});
```

you can do

```
const router = new Router(routes);

function renderRoute(location) {
  router.resolve({ path: location.pathname }).then(component => {
    render(component, document.getElementById('router-outlet'));
  });
}

renderRoute(window.location);
```

and then call `renderRoute` whenever the window path changes.

With `history`, it makes this easier by providing a listener and several other useful features. All you gotta do is create a single instance and use it throughout your app.

Make a singleton somewhere (ie `history.js`)

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
export default createHistory();
```

And use it for both your nav

```
...
import history from './history.js';

export class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    history.push({
      pathname: event.currentTarget.pathname
    });
  }
  render() {
      return(
        <div>
            <a href="/" onClick={this.handleClick}>Root</a> |&nbsp;
            <a href="/home" onClick={this.handleClick}>Home</a> |&nbsp; 
            ...
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

and routing index

```
import history from './history.js'
...

renderRoute(history.location);

history.listen(renderRoute);
```

This [how-to](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/recipes/how-to-implement-routing.md) goes a bit more in depth, if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call router.resolve only once. This seems the reason why your app is always ended up with AboutComponent. Try to remove this part from your index.js:

```
router.resolve({ path: '/help' }).then(component => {
    ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById('router-outlet'));
});

router.resolve({ path: '/about' }).then(component => {
    ReactDOM.render(component, document.getElementById('router-outlet'));
});
```

Also, react-router is not deprecated. I recommend you to use react-router:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Comment: I did that. The resolve always fires, regardless of the actual path. I actually ditched the entire thing and use a different router now. I wasted a whole day on this crap.